# Boolean not registering as true for string equivalence

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I'm parsing some XML with BeautifulSoup and have data that looks like:

```
soup.FindAll('title')

<title>main title</title>
<title>other title</title>
<title>another title</title>
```

When iterating over the tags, I want to skip the first title. So I have:

```
for e in soup.findAll('title'):
    if e == '<title>main title</title>':
        pass
    else:
        print (e)
```

This still returns all the titles, including `main title`. I've tried removing the title tags as well.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You boolean is not working as you want to compare an object `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>` to string, it will always be False. You could convert it to string then compare them.

Try this:

```
for e in soup.find_all("title"):
    if str(e) == '<title>main title</title>':
        pass
    else:
        print (e)
```

Output:

```
<title>other title</title>
<title>another title</title>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to skip the first title, then a better solution is to slice the list:

```
>>> soup.findAll('title')[1:]
[<title>other title</title>, <title>another title</title>]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the text attribute of the node, instead of the node itself.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup("""<title>main title</title>
<title>other title</title>
<title>another title</title>""", "html.parser")

for e in soup.find_all("title"):
    if e.text != 'main title':
        print(e)

#<title>other title</title>
#<title>another title</title>
```